Getting geometry and only a few properties with a WFS request
I'm using a web feature service to get point features from Belgium with Python. Each point (monitoring wells location) contain several attributes of which only 2 are relevant for what I need. I also want the points to be in EPSG:4326. Requesting the features should be as fast as possible since they are getting plotted on a user interface
If I request the points using
URL = "https://www.dov.vlaanderen.be/geoserver/gw_meetnetten/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=gw_meetnetten:grondwaterlocaties_met_metingen&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=json"

I get the geometries in EPSG:4326 (which is what I want) plus all the attributes for each point, something that does not make much sense since I only need 2 of them.
When I include propertyname as a filter the request looks like:
URL = "https://www.dov.vlaanderen.be/geoserver/gw_meetnetten/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=gw_meetnetten:grondwaterlocaties_met_metingen&propertyname=filterfiche,gemeente&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=json

This request effectively filter the attributes, but for some reason does not return the geometry coordinates.
I would like to know if there is a way to build a request so that I only get the attributes that I want plus the data in EPSG:4326. Since I need this to be as fast as possible what I'm doing for the moment is getting 2 extra attributes, X_mL72, Y_mL72, which represent the point coordinates in EPSG:31370 and then I convert their coordinates locally with GeoPandas. This is faster than getting all attributes in EPSG:4326 and filtering the properties after, but I feel like it is slower that it would be to get exactly what I want from the service itself.

The geometry field is nillable in the schema as can be seen from the DescribeFeatureType response
https://www.dov.vlaanderen.be/geoserver/gw_meetnetten/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=describefeaturetype&typeName=gw_meetnetten:grondwaterlocaties_met_metingen
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="geom" nillable="true" type="gml:GeometryPropertyType"/>

Add "geom" into the list of propertyname and you will get the geometry as well:
https://www.dov.vlaanderen.be/geoserver/gw_meetnetten/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=gw_meetnetten:grondwaterlocaties_met_metingen&propertyname=geom,filterfiche,gemeente&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=json
The beginning of the response:
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "grondwaterlocaties_met_metingen.0",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    4.8668,
                    50.9291,
                    0
                ]
            },
            "geometry_name": "geom",
            "properties": {
                "filterfiche": "https://www.dov.vlaanderen.be/data/filter/1990-010707",
                "gemeente": "Tielt-Winge"
            }


That's exactly what I wanted. May I ask, what it means that the geometry field is nillable?

Nillable means that it does not need to exist in the response. It is rather common in WFS that the geometry field is not nillable. In that case it is mandatory and WFS resultset contains it always whether a user wants it or not. Also normal properties may be mandatory. But all that is documented in the schema. Fortunately there is DescribeFeatureType.
